# Document created with id returned but can't find in database Firebase and Vue.js

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to integrate Google Firestore to my vue.js web app.
I have attached a function that creates a document to my "register" button and also put some logs to see if the document is successfully created.

When i hit the button i get the next message:

> Document written with ID:  zJxWy2pu3xRcR8jCb2ZI

Still, i can't see the document in the collection.

I've tried adding logs to the function and everything seems to work without any errors and i even get a successfully created message.

```
methods: {
formSubmit() {

    const project = {
        'userName': this.fullname,
        'userEmail': this.email,
        'userPass': this.password
    }

    db.collection('users').add(project).then(function(docRef) {
        console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
    })
    .catch(error => {
    console.error('There was an error editing the record: ' + error)
    })
  //this.$router.push("/");
}


}
```

Also, this is how i initialize firebase:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'

var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "key",
    authDomain: "domain",
    databaseURL: "url",
    projectId: "id",
    storageBucket: "bucket",
    messagingSenderId: "id",
    appId: "app_id"
};
// Initialize Firebase
try {
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} catch (err) {

}
const db = firebase.firestore();

export default db;
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot of your firestore db structure.

Comment: https://gyazo.com/573c3403be19ed5319cb0e00827c333a

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.
Apparently, i was opening a connection to the database in a different document.

As i was using "try{}" without logging any error, i didn't realize and the connection wasn't actually opening.